# Defining a function that takes an array of numbers and returns the index when the numbers stop increasing and begin decreasing (python)

Tags: python

As the title suggests, I'm trying to define a function that takes an array of numbers and returns the index at which the numbers stop increasing and begin decreasing or stop decreasing and begin increasing. For example, if the array were [1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 1], the function should return 3. The following code only returns the left bracket, and I'm wondering why that is the case.

```
def ArrayChallenge(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
            return i
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) is it literally returning the left bracket character ‘[‘? 2) are you essentially just trying to find the index of the highest value?

Comment: Correct, it was literally returning the left bracket character "[". And not entirely, the first part is to find where the numbers stop increasing and begin to decrease, so I believe the max would work for that. However, if an inputted sequence were [10, 9, 8, 7, 9, 2, 1], then the function should return 4 since it stopped decreasing at index 4 of the list. Additionally, if there is no point of inflection in the sequence, then I'd like to return -1; i.e. [-5, -2, 0, 1, 7, 8] should just return -1.

Comment: I am not able to replicate your bracket issue. The code you provided worked fine

Comment: "The following code only returns the left bracket" That happens because what was supplied to the function **was not a list** (we don't call them "arrays" in Python), but a **string**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I tried op’s code as a string and it returned 0, not the character

Comment: Right, `0` being the index of that character. So in any event the described behaviour is either not reproducible, or at least not the fault of the code that is shown. When I try the code with the input `[1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 1]` (a list), the result is `3` (as desired). Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was my version of visual studio code that was causing the problem. The left bracket only printed out when I was running it locally on VS code. It was fine in a repl and when using colab.

Anyways, I wanted to post the solution I came up with... It took me a little longer than I would like to admit, but I suppose this is to be expected being new to programming. Here is my code for the problem. I welcome any and all critiques.

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if (arr[0] == min(arr) and arr[-1] == max(arr)) or (arr[0] == max(arr) and arr[-1] == min(arr)):
        return -1
    if arr[i+1] > arr[i]:
        return arr.index(max(arr))
    else:
        return arr.index(min(arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your array will always increase and then decrease with no duplicated highest value, you’re essentially looking for the highest value in the list. An easier option is to simply find the max value and return its index. If that is not the case, this may lead you to your solution:

```
def ArrayChallenge(arr):
    return arr.index(max(arr))
```

Edit: Given poster’s comments, the following should work (but is not the nicest looking). An assumption here is that the first cannot be used since it did not have a lower preceding value and the last cannot because it does not have a lower following value:

```
def ArrayChallenge(arr):
    peaks = []
    for i in range(1, len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i - 1] < arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:
            peaks.append(i)
    return peaks if len(peaks) > 0 else -1
```

Comment: Please only answer questions where there is a reproducible problem. "An easier approach to the task" is not on topic here (except incidentally as part of resolving an actual problem); that is the purview of [codereview.se].